# Use AQL Variables e.g. for counting (LET sum = sum + 1)

Tags: arangodb

According to https://www.arangodb.com/2014/07/13/arangodb-2-2-0-released it shall be possible to use statements like this:

```
LET sum = 0
FOR v IN values
  SORT v.year
  LET sum = sum + v.value
  RETURN { year: v.year, value: v.value, sum: sum }
```

I currently use version 2.4 but am not able to use it, e.g. in such a statement:

```
LET sum = 0
FOR i in memoryColl
    LET sum = sum + 1
    // sum = sum + 1
    RETURN { "i": i, "sum": sum }
```

I got the error 
    [1511] variable 'sum' is assigned multiple times (while parsing)

Can somebody tell me if such a statemtn should in principle work, and how exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the [upgrading docs](https://docs.arangodb.com/Upgrading/UpgradingChanges23.html#variables-not-updatable-in-queries) for 2.3, it's no longer possible to update variables in queries:

> Previous versions of ArangoDB allowed the modification of variables inside AQL
>   queries [...]
>
> While this is admittedly a convenient feature, the **new query optimizer design did not
>   allow to keep it**.
>
> Additionally, updating variables inside a query **would prevent a lot
>   of optimizations** to queries that we would like the optimizer to make. Additionally,
>   updating variables in queries that run on different nodes **in a cluster would like cause
>   non-deterministic behavior** because queries are not executed linearly.

To enumerate documents, you could do

```
LET range = 0..LENGTH(memoryColl)-1

FOR i IN range
    RETURN {i: i+1, doc: memoryColl[i]}
```

but it looks like a really bad idea to me. Better return the documents and let the client enumerate them.

If you actually want to count the number of documents, you may use a sub-query:

```
LET result = (
    FOR doc IN memoryColl
        FILTER True // add some condition here for instance
        RETURN doc
)

RETURN LENGTH(result)
```

In 2.4, it is also possible to count more efficiently:
http://jsteemann.github.io/blog/2014/12/12/aql-improvements-for-24/

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. So, the topic is closed for me. But just as a remark: of course, counting can be done in other ways, too - this example was just to simplify the question. I originally thought about examples where such updateable variables could significantly help to express/shortify the necessary calculations, esp. in combination with filters which stop the calculation when a variable gets a certain value and so on.
But its clear to me that this would disable other optimizations and parallelizations, so also your priorities are clear for me.

==> THANKS again for your answer.

Comment: You may wanna check on ArangoDB actions / Foxx if you really need such functionality, they allow for custom JavaScript code running in the database - with more or less the same drawbacks regarding performance I worry however.

Answer (score 1):

On arango 3.7 in 2020 you could do something like described [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/arangodb/sum%7Csort:date/arangodb/BWTNkZ9e9W4/Ss74q1boAgAJ)

```
LET values = [
    { year: 2019, value: 35 },
    { year: 2017, value: 8 },
    { year: 2018, value: 17 },
    { year: 2020, value: 84 }
]

LET sortedValues = (FOR v IN values SORT v.year RETURN v)
FOR i IN 0..LENGTH(sortedValues)-1
    LET v = sortedValues[i]
    LET sum = sortedValues[i].value + SUM(SLICE(sortedValues, 0, i)[*].value)
    RETURN {year:v.year,value:v.value,sum:sum}
```

This returned

```
[
  {
    "year": 2017,
    "value": 8,
    "sum": 8
  },
  {
    "year": 2018,
    "value": 17,
    "sum": 25
  },
  {
    "year": 2019,
    "value": 35,
    "sum": 60
  },
  {
    "year": 2020,
    "value": 84,
    "sum": 144
  }
]
```